# HTTP status 404-Page not found. SpringMVC error

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

It is my first application in SpringMVC using Maven.
here is the application structure.

[image]

Controller code:

[image]

When I click on the link in the index.jsp the page should be traversed to helloworld.jsp

index.jsp has this link:

```
    <h3>
        <a href="hello?name=Eric">Click Here</a>
    </h3>
```

helloworld.jsp

```
    <h2>
        ${message} ${name}
    </h2>
```

The code for dispatcher servlet:

[image]

Update: web.xml file.

[image]

I understand that it's a silly question, but as a newbie to SpringMVC structure, I am not able to find the error. Please help!

Spring is starting up. 
This is the homepage, when I click on the link, it should be traversed to helloworld.jsp.

[image]

And this is the pom.xml.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>demoproject</groupId>
 <artifactId>demoMVC</artifactId>

 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>demoMVC Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
 </properties>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 <build>
   <finalName>demoMVC</finalName>
    <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>  
       <plugins>  
            <plugin>  
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
                 <version>3.3</version>  
                 <configuration>  
                      <source>1.8</source>  
                      <target>1.8</target>  
                      <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>  
                 </configuration>  
            </plugin>  
       </plugins>  
     </build>
   </project>
```

Console:

```
  WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting    property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:demoMVC' did not find a matching property.
  Mar 31, 2017 1:22:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
  INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
  Mar 31, 2017 1:22:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
  INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
  Mar 31, 2017 1:22:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
  INFO: Initialization processed in 1005 ms
  Mar 31, 2017 1:22:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
  INFO: Starting service Catalina
   Mar 31, 2017 1:22:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
   Mar 31, 2017 1:22:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
   INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
   Mar 31, 2017 1:22:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
   Mar 31, 2017 1:22:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
  INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
   Mar 31, 2017 1:22:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
   INFO: Server startup in 3739 ms
```

Comment: It looks good. What about the pom.xml? Also what is is the logs? Is spring starting up? The dispatcher is getting the requests?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: What about the logs when you click on the link?

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the logs you should see something like:

```
19:05:56,530 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
19:05:56,531 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
19:05:56,547 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Mar 31 19:05:56 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
19:05:56,584 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
19:05:56,741 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
19:05:56,859 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Mapped "{[/hello],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto protected org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.crramirez.HelloWorldController.showMessage(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
19:05:57,084 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 553 ms
```

Delete these lines in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and rename the file in WEB-INF from **dispatcher-servlet.xml** to **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

With this your program should work.

Comment: Hello, I updated the code as you suggested. Still its giving 404 error. Also, I do not see anything like that in console.

Comment: You should be seeing a lot of errors or at least a message that your application was deployed. Check if your are in fact putting the war in the right place in the tomcat server

Comment: My program works fine but there is a problem when I try to traverse it to a second page. From index.jsp to helloworld.jsp does not work. And what I updated in my question, is all I am getting from Console.

Comment: If helloworld.jsp doesn't work is because probably spring framework is not starting up. And it is very strange that your log only shows this. Try to deploy in a conventional way, packing your app in a war file using maven install and copying the resulting war to the webapps directory of your tomcat installation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139626/discussion-between-trin-and-carlos-rafael-ramirez).